# Bevel in 2.81 is not the same as in 2.8

Tags: bevel

I am a beginner and I am modeling a technical piece in blender 2.81 and I can't get the same result as in youtube video (2.8) I use:
https://youtu.be/WSR6bVFe5LM?t=974

Either bevel is broken in a newer version or I am doing something wrong...

This is what author of the video has, what I need:
[image]
So he selected 2 "bottom" edges, clicked Ctrl+B for bevel filled in amount & segments count = 12, that's all!

What I have in blender 2.81:
[image]
**I tried to change bevel types & parameters but I can't get the same result!**

Also, I can't apply transformations for some reason:
[image]
I go to the object mode, press Ctrl+A, select All transformation OR just Scale but scaling numbers are not changing, so it is not applied??

Please help me to get the same results as author of the video has... I am stuck for 3 weeks already with this issue :(

A link to a blender file + reference image in case someone want to try on his PC:
[one drive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqmUVNIKdVd-jEdrtM95ZCoTmR_h?e=9KCYd0)

Comment: Apply the scale of the object. Ctrl A in object mode.

Comment: my mistake was that I didn't select object in OM before applying transformations :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

holy smokes! I've realized my error! it is not enough just apply "all transformations" in objects mode, **before that you need to select the object itself**! that was a key... now all is working as needed!

p.s: why blender doesn't show an error if you haven't selected anything!?

Comment: Make sure to mark this as the answer